# Test side effects in Redux actions

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk, nock

I'm working through the Redux tutorial found [here](http://rackt.org/redux/index.html).

In the app that I've created, I have an action with a side effect just as the one shown [here](http://rackt.org/redux/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html#action-creators-and-constants) in the receivePosts function where Date.now() is called.

The side effect is triggered after an async function is completed. When following [this async test](http://rackt.org/redux/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html#async-action-creators) in my own app. I get a response looking like this:

```
actual: 
{ 
  type: 'REQUEST_LEAGUE_SUCCESS',
  receivedAt: 1453991947254,
  league: 'Div 3',
  resultsTable: [ [Object], [Object] ] 
},

expected: 
{ 
  type: 'REQUEST_LEAGUE_SUCCESS',
  league: 'Div 3',
  receivedAt: 1453991947235,
  resultsTable: [ [Object], [Object] ]
}
```

where the date from my expected action is not equal to the date from the actual action. In my expected action, I have the following:

```
receivedAt: Date.now()
```

The structure of my code is exactly the same as the code found in the Redux tutorial, apart from my action creator having this side effect.

My question boils down to: How do I handle these side effects to make my tests pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test code that relies on grabbing the current time is not a good idea.  You'll need rewrite things so that you can mock out or inject a date.  Some good examples of doing that at ([Unit Tests, How to Write Testable Code and Why it Matters](http://www.toptal.com/qa/how-to-write-testable-code-and-why-it-matters)). That article is C#-based, but the same same concept applies here.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock Date.now() function like this:

```
describe('>>> Test Name', () => {
    const literallyJustNow = Date.now();
    const realDateNow = Date.now.bind(global.Date);
    const dateNowStub = jest.fn(() => literallyJustNow);

    beforeEach(() => {
        global.Date.now = dateNowStub;
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        global.Date.now = realDateNow;
    });

    it('... your tests ...', () => { ... });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to build in some tolerance into your tests, as some amount of time will inevitably pass between dispatching an action and receiving a response. Even if your faking it, there will still be a difference in execution time. How you actually go about doing this depends on your assertion library.